# What can you do if you think there might be a better answer than the received one?

Tags: support, not-an-answer

What should you do if you receive a working answer, which you think is cumbersome, not simple/elegant or contentive of too many lines?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can:

- wait and hope someone else provides a better answer
- ask the answerer to improve their answer (via a comment)
- edit your question to clarify your requirement
- downvote
- place a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

I'd recommend clarifying your requirements, either by editing your question or commenting; these actions provide helpful information to the original answerer and other potential answerers.  Downvoting is less clear - it may not be obvious why you downvoted - and waiting/bounty both require you to wait longer than you might like.

Answer (score 5):

- Downvote the answer if you feel it is bad enough as to be not useful.
- Post a better answer.